# Write SQL query for the below output

Tags: mysql, sql

The table is as below.

```
Emp_ID  Emp_Name  Emp_Manager_ID
01           A      10
02           B      11
03           C      10
04           D      11
05           E      10
06           F      11
07           G      10
08           H      11
09           I      10
10           J      11
11           K      10
12           L      11
```

If the requirement is to get the emp_ID and their manager's name, how to write the query?

Like below.

```
Emp_ID  Emp_Name  Emp_Manager_ID  Emp_Manager_Name
01          A           10             J
02          B           11             K
```

Comment: Simply do a self join to get the manager name.

Answer (score 0):

A simple self join should do it.

```
SELECT t1.emp_id,
       t1.emp_name,
       t1.emp_manager_id,
       t2.emp_name emp_manager_name
       FROM elbat t1
            LEFT JOIN elbat t2
                      ON t2.emp_id = t1.emp_manager_id;
```